# How do I receive an excel file as input using Flask and read it using openpyxl?

Tags: python, flask, openpyxl

I've created a python script that loads an excel file up from my computer and, after working with the information inside it using openpyxl, saves a new excel file. **The script works on my computer.** For longevity purposes, I want to make the script into a website, using pythonanywhere or something similar to it (incorporating flask seemed like the best way to convert my script into a website). However, I am having trouble finding a way to accept a file from the user, as I have very little experience using flask. Here's the code I currently have that creates a "choose file" button and a "process file" button:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config["DEBUG"] = True

@app.route("/", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def file_summer_page():
    if request.method == ("POST"):
        input_file = request.files["input_file"]
        wb_master = load_workbook(input_file)
        output_data = main(wb_master)
        response = make_response(output_data)
        response.headers["Content-Disposition"] = "attachment; filename=result.csv"
        return response

    return '''
        <html>
            <body>
                <p>Load up the automated eval that MS Forms gives you:</p>
                <form method="post" action="." enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <p><input type="file" name="input_file" /></p>
                    <p><input type="submit" value="Process the file" /></p>
                </form>
            </body>
        </html>
    '''
```

Bear with me. Again, I haven't used Flask much, but this is my idea so far. Main(wb_master) essentially calls the script I made, so that it could hopefully run. At the moment, this returns the following error: "AttributeError: 'SpooledTemporaryFile' object has no attribute 'seekable'." In this case, I don't really know what it means, but I assume it is due to the fact that I am not reading the file correctly. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I'm guessing that the exception is coming out of your `load_workbook` function -- could you share the code you have in there?

Comment: I'm guessing that the exception is coming out of your `load_workbook` function -- could you share the code you have in there?

Comment: The load_workbook function is one that comes with the openpyxl package. It seemed to work well when I ran the script locally.

Comment: Maybe you could copy the file that Flask provides on the request object to a temporary file, and then use `load_workbook` to load that?  It looks like Flask in production mode is handling the streaming of uploaded files differently to how it does in debug/dev mode.